# ember-intl adds 600+ json for different languages to the project while building

Tags: ember.js, ember-i18n

We are using ember-intl in our projects. But while we are building our projects with `ember build --environment=production`, ember-intl adds 600+ translations files.

I want to pick the languages that we support and I don't want to add 17mb of json files those we don't need.

Is there any configuration for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the below in `config/environment.js`.

```
intl: {
    locales: ['en-us', 'fr-fr']
 }
```

included sample environment.js file would be,

```
var ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'kuman-appname',
    environment: environment,
    baseURL: '/',
    locationType: 'auto',
    EmberENV: {
      FEATURES: {
        // Here you can enable experimental features on an ember canary build
        // e.g. 'with-controller': true
      }
    },

    APP: {
      // Here you can pass flags/options to your application instance
      // when it is created
    },
    intl: {
       locales: ['en-us', 'fr-fr']
     }
  }
```

https://github.com/jasonmit/ember-intl/wiki/Intl.js-Polyfill#loading-files-from-assets